# Excel 2016 - Multiple Sheet Instances

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'll have to explain this with an example..

**Sheet 1:** I have one sheet whose contents are conditional - I change say Cell **A1** and **B1**, and the whole sheet changes based on these. Cell **C1** is read by Sheet 2.

**Sheet 2:** This is a scenario based sheet - it has multiple tables for considering certain situations. The trouble is however, the tables in this sheet cannot 'inject' values into the cells in Sheet 1 to receive the resultant value(s) for each conditional circumstance.

So the question essentially is:
**Is it possible to create a template sheet** (with conditions and formulae) **which can be instantiated with differing values in each instance?**

If this could be the case, I could access the cells of the sheet object.

**More Information:** Sheet 1 could be thought of as a pRNG algorithm, with cells in Sheet 2 providing seeds to it. The seed for Sheet 1 cannot be hard coded, as Sheet 2 deals with differing seeds.

Thinking about this programmatically, I'd set up all the formulae in Sheet1, and then do something like:

```
Dim Alg1 as Sheet1
Alg1.Range("A1").Value = 34512
Alg1.Range("B1").Value = 54312

Sheet2.Range("C7").Value = Alg1.Range("C1").Value
```

All whilst being able to make changes to Sheet1 and have them reflected in Alg1.

Comment: so you want sheet 1 to be dependent on sheet 2, and sheet 2 to be dependent on sheet 1?

Comment: Not quite; I'm not really talking about dependencies. I just want to have like a template approach instead of hard typing in values into sheets.